# Como eliminar linhas duplicadas sem uso do distinct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tabela-temporária

A query abaixo me retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
       IF object_id('tempdb..#tmpHistorico') IS NOT NULL 
            BEGIN
                 DROP TABLE #tmpHistorico
            END

            CREATE TABLE #tmpHistorico
            (
                Id              int not null,
                IdColuna1       int not null,
                IdColuna2       int not null,
                Valor1          varchar(10) not null,
                Valor2          varchar(10) not null,
                DataAtualizacao DateTime not null
            )

        insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,1,1,'100',    '2000','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,2,2,'100',   '99999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,2,2,'100',  '200000','2018-04-10 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,3,3,'100',  '259999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,4,4,'100',  '109999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,4,4,'100',    '9999','2018-04-10 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,5,5,'100', '2559999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (2,6,6,'100',  '159999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (2,6,6,'100',  '309999','2018-04-10 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (2,7,7,'100',  '559999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')

            select Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao 
    from #tmpHistorico where Id= 1
```

**DÚVIDA** 
Como faço para eliminar as linhas duplicadas ?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que a query me retorne as linhas com `DataAtualizacao` **mais Recente** e **elimine a mais antiga**, e fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para confirmar meu entendimento. Você quer retornar os resultados agrupados por `IdColuna1` que possuem a maior `DataAtualizacao` correto?

Comment: Agrupado por IdColuna1 e IdColuna2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM #tmpHistorico t1
 WHERE t1.DataAtualizacao = (SELECT MAX(t2.DataAtualizacao)
                               FROM #tmpHistorico t2
                              WHERE t2.IdColuna1 = t1.IdColuna1
                                AND t2.IdColuna2 = t1.IdColuna2);
```

Para tornar essa solução mais performática você pode indexar as colunas `DataAtualizacao`, `IdColuna1` e `IdColuna2`.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro você criar uma nova tabela temporária pra controlar o que será ou não exibido, já que isso não pode ser feito pelo `Id`.

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#tmpHistorico') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #tmpHistorico END
IF object_id('tempdb..#tmpHistoricoMaxData') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #tmpHistoricoMaxData END

CREATE TABLE #tmpHistorico
(
    Id              int not null,
    IdColuna1       int not null,
    IdColuna2       int not null,
    Valor1          varchar(10) not null,
    Valor2          varchar(10) not null,
    DataAtualizacao DateTime not null
)

insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,1,1,'100',    '2000','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,2,2,'100',   '99999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,2,2,'100',  '200000','2018-04-10 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,3,3,'100',  '259999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,4,4,'100',  '109999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,4,4,'100',    '9999','2018-04-10 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (1,5,5,'100', '2559999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (2,6,6,'100',  '159999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (2,6,6,'100',  '309999','2018-04-10 00:00:00.000')
insert #tmpHistorico (Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, Valor1, Valor2, DataAtualizacao) values (2,7,7,'100',  '559999','2018-04-09 00:00:00.000')

CREATE TABLE #tmpHistoricoMaxData
(
    Id              int not null,
    IdColuna1       int not null,
    IdColuna2       int not null,
    DataAtualizacao DateTime not null
)

insert into #tmpHistoricoMaxData
select Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2, max(DataAtualizacao) 
from #tmpHistorico
group by Id, IdColuna1, IdColuna2

select tmp.Id, tmp.IdColuna1, tmp.IdColuna2, tmp.Valor1, tmp.Valor2, tmp.DataAtualizacao 
from #tmpHistorico tmp
join #tmpHistoricoMaxData tmpDt on tmp.Id = tmpDt.Id and tmp.IdColuna1 = tmpDt.IdColuna1 and tmp.IdColuna2 = tmpDt.IdColuna2 and tmp.DataAtualizacao = tmpDt.DataAtualizacao
where tmp.Id= 1
```